# Can new users edit their own question?

Tags: discussion, editing

Can new users with 1 rep edit their own question? I'll often comment on new users posts with suggestions on how to make them better, but they respond back with comments and not edits.

I'm looking to confirm that users with 1 rep can infact, edit their own question.

Comment: this could be answered by creating a new account and testing the functionality ....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.  New users with 1 rep [can](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) edit their own question.

I suspect the phenomenom you noticed is mainly caused by:

- The fact that people are more used to forums, where the preferred way is to add a new post to the conversation instead of editing the initial post,
- Maybe to a less extent that the "add a comment" link may be more visible than the edit one.

A user can always edit their own posts without any reputation prerequisite (this concerns both questions and answers without time limitation and comment during a few minutes only). Do not hesitate to encourage them to use the "edit" link instead of adding new comments. The first edit will even be awarded by the "Editor" badge :).

Moreover any user can also propose edits to any posts, however while their reputation is below 2000 their edit proposal will need to be reviewed before becoming active.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I was looking for a hard reference for "a user can always edit their own posts".

Comment: @amccormack: It is one of the basis of this site, so I guess the best "hard reference" you may find would be the [Tour](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour) page where new users are explicitly encouraged to "*Use edits to fix mistakes, improve formatting, or clarify the meaning of a post.*"

Comment: @amccormack [Meta.SE's FAQ post, "How does editing work?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work): "**The original author of a question or answer may edit their own post.** Additionally, users with a certain level of reputation may edit any question or answer. The one exception is locked questions, which may not be edited by anyone, including the original author, until they are unlocked."